# Usage of the phrase "a battery of"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I have read "a battery of lawyers" and "a battery of test" in sentences with its usage.

What I would like to know is, are the following sentences are correct with the usage of a battery of

- A battery of attempts was made to resurrect his life
- A battery of development methods was used to create an application
- A battery of sketches was considered before arriving at a final decision.

Appreciate any insight and could anyone enlighten about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster's 5th definition of battery, specifically relating to "a battery of"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/battery)

> a (1): a number of similar articles, items, or devices arranged,
>   connected, or used together

Examples: They ran him through a battery of tests.  They offered a battery of filing cabinets.

> b: a usually impressive
>   or imposing group, array

Example: After finishing my drawing, it was shown to a battery of specialists.

[Dictionary.com's 2nd 4th and definitions](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/battery)

> 2: any large group or series of related things
>
> 4: a group or series of similar articles, machines, parts, etc.

Battery comes from a Middle French word meaning bombardment or assault.  This is most likely why the word is most often used with "battery of questions" or "battery of tests" to imply that one has been bombarded with many questions or tests.  In addition, in modern English we still use battery in the context of "assault and battery."  [And "to batter" means to "beat with successive blows."](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/batter)

So while "a battery of" can be used to talk about a group of similar things, the word also has a strong connotation of assault.  And that should be considered when using it.

For your provided example sentences, all of them are correct. I would suggest that they also imply a rigorous process because of the use of "battery."  But I think that is in line with what the sentences are trying to convey.

Comment: Excellent answer and much appreciated for enlightening with different scenarios and for providing the context to use the word concisely.